# Sub categories Images in top horizontal menu Prestashop 1.6

Tags: menu, prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.6

I would like to have sub category images along with the heading on hovering through the category in top horizontal menu. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add images in the main categories and the subcategories? If you do that, the default PrestaShop horizontal menu adds the pictures automatically in the menu.

It even makes the whole category structure. It has to be indexed or something, or empty cache, because it will take a while otherwise (I'm not sure how to make it take effect immediately).